# Error "System is booting up. See pam_nologin(8)"

Tags: startup, pam

This morning, I see this error message showed in lightdm login interface, and cannot enter password.

So I went to TTY1 and saw:

```
[**   ] A start job is running for monitor and control system power state (2min 45s / 3min 1s)
```

after waiting, it FAILED.

I went to TTY2, also can not enter password after typing my username.

Does anyone know why this happened? Possible Bug?

Restarting the machine, I can get the recovery console.

Comment: I got the same bug. :/

Comment: Here is the bug report: <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/1591622>. I will try the workarounds (reboot until it works, or downgrade a package).

Comment: @YannDìnendal's link has an extra > in it, so clicking on it leads it to a 404 error. Here is the link again: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/1591622. By the way, a simple restart would probably suffice.

Comment: I dont know why this question is closed, but this happened to me on Ubuntu server 20.04 after changing the user password from recovery as root and then switching to tty2 to test. I was able to login after rebooting. (probably caused by 'single user mode', the recovery mode.

Answer (score -2):

I just did a hard restart. Turn your computer off, unplug all accessories (cords, exterior cooling fan, joysticks, etc.), take yor battery out, hold power button down for 60 secs, put the battery back in, and restart the computer.

Worked for me. Good luck.